# check for internet timeout

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I'm creating a app. I need to check if internet is available. I used URLMonitor to check if internet is available or not. It's working fine. But sometimes if internet is too slow then it takes very long time to check. I want to know, if we can reduce timeout length to 3 to 5 seconds only ?

Comment: yes use settimeoutconnection method in httpconeection

Comment: Can you be little more specific ?

Comment: u r createing app in native android?

Comment: I'm creating app in flash cs 5.5 as3.

Comment: Should load a 1x1 gif.  You need to know if you can actually load stuff, not just if the phone thinks there's a connection.  Plus, loading something will keep the connection open if there's a timeout.  Put a unique id on the end of url to keep from loading the cache.

Answer (score 0):

There is no timeout property in URLMonitor. You may try to set your own Timer and start/stop URLMonitor manually. However, I do not see significant benefits. URLMonitor checks just returned HTTP code. I doubt that it loads the whole piece of the information from the provided url. This means, that you can hardly count on the internet if status code has not been received.

If this functionality is really crucial to your app, you may also try to use native extension. There are several one, both for iOS and Android. Just google for them.